# Bootstrap data table styles not applied in wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins, datatables

I am trying to use Bootstrap Datatables (https://datatables.net/manual/installation) on a wordpress page that I "inject" with `add_shortcode()`, but it looks quite bad:
The first 2 lines are date pickers, but then the entries select box, the search bar and the pagination at the bottom look out of place...
I already imported the stylesheet and scripts with

```
wp_register_script( 'datatablejs', 'http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js');
wp_register_style('datatables_styles', 'http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css');

wp_enqueue_script('datatables_styles');
wp_enqueue_script('datatablejs');
```

but I don't know how to fix the styles so that it looks "normal"...
I am also using bootstrap 4 styles, maybe that interferes with the datatables styles? I created my table inside a php file for wordpress... :

```
function renderTable() {
global $finishedData;

$table ="";
$table .= '<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <input id="start-date" > <input id="end-date">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                <table id="pruefungentable"  class="table striped dark" style="width: 100%">
                    <thead class="thead-dark ">
                        <tr scope="row" class="table-danger">
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>AID</th>
                            <!--<th>BID</th>-->
                            <th>OID</th>
                            <th>Mod</th>
                            <th>Datum</th>      
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>';
                    $count = 0;
                    foreach($finishedData as $entry) {
                        $ID = ++$count;
                        $ID=$entry["ID"];
                        $BID=$entry["BID"];
                        $MOD=$entry["MOD"];
                        $Datum=$entry["Datum"]; 

                        $table .=   "<tr><td>" .  $ID . "</td>";
                        $table .=    "<td>" .  $AID . "</td>";
                        $table .= "<td>" . $BID . "</td>";
                        $table .= "<td>" . $MOD ."</td>";
                        $table .= "<td>". strftime("%d.%m.%Y",strtotime($Datum)) ."</td></tr>";
            
                    } 
$table .=           '</tbody>
                    </table>     
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';

return $table;
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the styles and the JS files are actually loaded by checking the developer tools (inspect) and that there is no errors in the console and check if other styles maybe overwriting the data tables styles, also try adding the links to the header by using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/